# mysql - php - List only records for the current day

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to display via mysql-php, a daily list of events, but as far as the (day name & date ) are concerned only show the actual day/date heading eg " Friday 26th Oct " once if there are multiple entries for that day.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Field 1 contains a textual date eg 10 26 2012 , which is set by a tinymce popup calendar.
the list
Field 2 contains event Title.

Field 3 contains event Details

I need to display the list data horizontally and to do that i use a table nested within php code.

```
<?php
    $start_date = "STR_TO_DATE(field_1,'%m %d %Y') AS startDate, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(field_1,'%m %d %Y'),'%D %b %Y') AS startDate";
    $query= "SELECT * ,$start_date FROM events ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(field_1,'%m %d %Y') ASC ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['startDate'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['field_2'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['field_3'];?></td>
        </tr></table>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

1. replacing the order by by the already converted date to avoid multiple time convertinge
2. filter by startdate = DATE(NOW())

$query= "SELECT * ,$start_date FROM events WHERE startDate = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY startDate ASC ";

Comment: Preferrably use `CUR_DATE()` instead of `NOW()`

Comment: Preferably use CURRENT_DATE as it is standards compliant

Comment: I tried Both those but get the same response " mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given "

Comment: Did you check the output of [mysql_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
TO_CHAR( $start_dt, 'mm-dd-yy' )
```

Comment: Same response as above Randy ,  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given